# How to fix "android.app.RemoteServiceException in android?"

Tags: android, remoteserviceexception

My app got "android.app.RemoteServiceException" exception. I've use the "JobScheduler" to instead of "Service". It worked, besides OPPO 8.1. 
That's all message i got.

```
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1987)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:187)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7025)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:514)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

Comment: Have you been able to find any solution? I also got the same problem.

Comment: Me too, any solutions?

Comment: Useless stack trace. I'm getting the same too...

Comment: These links may help: https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons/issues/1877 and https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons/pull/1904

Answer (score 0):

This was happening for me too after migrating to `JobScheduler`. Turned out there were some alarms scheduled by the previous app version that would still try to launch the migrated service in the foreground. I fixed it by renaming the `JobService` class, that way the system could no longer locate it when one of those prior alarms would trigger.